# Uploading a blob to an S3 bucket using PutObject doesn't work: SignatureDoesNotMatch. Why?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Attempting to upload an image to an S3 bucket, as a blob, fails with the following error:

```
<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calcul (truncated...) 
SignatureDoesNotMatch (client): The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method. - <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

The credentials are pulled from a `/.aws/credentials` file and I know for a fact that they work, because `putObject` from a file works perfectly. It's just the blob that fails to upload.

The S3 class has the following parts that are of interest, in this case:

```
class S3_model extends CI_Model {

private $s3Client;
private $s3Config = [
    'version' => '2006-03-01',      // See `version` parameter documentation here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/guide/configuration.html
    'region' => 'eu-central-1'
];

private $bucket = 'tprdev';

public function __construct ()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('log_model');
    $this->s3Client = new Aws\S3\S3Client($this->s3Config);
}

public function putObjectFromBlob ($key, $blob)
{
    try {
        $params = [
            'Bucket' => $this->bucket,
            'Key'    => $key,
            'Body'   => $blob
        ];

        $this->s3Client->putObject($params);
        $this->s3Client->waitUntil('ObjectExists', $params);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->log_model->log("{$e->getMessage()}\n{$e->getTraceAsString()}");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, this new version of the SDK that I've used is fussy about object keys with a leading slash. I've removed the leading slash and the blobs now upload.

Comment: The error (imho) was actually in the older SDKs being too permissive.  A leading slash in object keys has always *technically* been wrong -- at the risk of being pedantic, the `/` signifies the root of the bucket but is not actually the first character of the object key (there is no object named `/`) -- but the older code tolerated it by treating it as optional.  I don't know if that was accidental or deliberate ("helpful") design. +1 for sorting out your own issue.